# Как правильно поднять сервер на Azure?

Tags: c#, сервер, azure

Имеется код сервера

`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceAddress = "127.0.0.1:10000";
            var serviceName = "MyService";

            var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TransferObject), new Uri($"net.tcp://{serviceAddress}/{serviceName}"));
            var serverBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITransferObject), serverBinding, "");
            host.Open();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

`

код взят с [сайта](https://vc.ru/dev/177588-prostoy-i-nadezhnyy-c-klient-server-ispolzuya-wcf)

Как правильно запустить серверную часть в Azure, нужно создать виртуальную машину и на нем уже запускать сервер или как веб-задание или как приложение-функция?
Если смотрю не туда,то пожалуйста подскажите как это делается.
Спасибо за ваше время.

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать что-то на Azure, то смотрите документацию [Azure для разработчиков .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/azure/). Зачем вы касаетесь технологии WCF (которая уже почти умерла, кстати)?

Comment: Что именно выбрать: web app, function или ещё что - зависит от ваших требований. Опишите задачу, которую решаете.

Comment: Чтобы поднять сервер, надо сначала его уронить. )) (простите, пол-второго ночи)

Comment: На примере этого кода хотел посмотреть как работает самая простейшая клиент-серверное приложение на Azure.

Comment: Если вы хотите клиент-**серверное** приложение, то зачем упоминаете **функции**, ведь они являются **serverless** function. И зачем на каких-то левых сайтах смотреть примеры кода устаревшей технологии WCF (хоть она мне нравится)? Открывайте официальную документацию: [Краткое руководство. Развертывание веб-приложения ASP.NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=netcore31&pivots=development-environment-vs)